# join two tables in oracle db with hibernate - one table has clob data

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hql

So I've been struggling with this for about 8 hours, and it's the last piece in my entire mobile app. Please help me convert this pseudo code into working HQL. I have a statement that works in H2 in memory database at the bottom, but my prod DB is oracle and it's picky as hell. I'm trying to get the leaderboard and add the base64 image. Even if I remove the distinct the working H2 statement below it doesnt run still with error `

> inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

.

Statement I can't get to work in HQL:

```
select a.*, b.image 
from (select distinct score.staffId as staffId, 
      sum(score.totalScore) as totalScore, 
      sum(score.timeTaken) as timeTaken from Score score) a 
join User b 
on a.staffId=b.staffId"
```

working statement in H2:

```
"select distinct score.staffId as staffId, 
        sum(score.totalScore) as totalScore, 
        sum(score.timeTaken) as timeTaken, 
        user.image as image"
+ " from Score score, User user"
+ " where score.staffId = user.staffId"
+ " group by score.staffId order by totalScore desc, timeTaken asc"
```

Comment: What is your table structure? Which columns are LOBs?

Comment: Your Oracle query is plain wrong, your H2 query as well (despite that it's working). Both suffer from a MySQL-related misbehaviour with aggregations miraculously working despite being incorrectly written.

Answer (score 0):

Despite that I don't know anything about HQL, I'll try and answer your question from a different point of view.

Rewrite your query as...

```
select a.*, b.image
from (
        select staffId,
            sum(totalScore) as totalScore,
            sum(timeTaken) as timeTaken
        from Score
        group by staffId
    ) a
    join User b
        on a.staffId = b.staffId
```

... and it should work.

If it still does not, then you have just witnessed the wonders of an Oracle query optimizer feature called "complex view merging" and you will have to help your Oracle DB slightly with the `no_merge` hint...

```
select a.*, b.image
from (
        select --+ no_merge
            staffId,
            sum(totalScore) as totalScore,
            sum(timeTaken) as timeTaken
        from Score
        group by staffId
    ) a
    join User b
        on a.staffId = b.staffId
```

As for your ORM, don't use it for DB reads, use plain SQL or jOOQ for those. [ORMs are perfect at writing stuff to DB, not at reading it.](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/11/30/do-you-need-an-orm/)